# How do I recover an image file Blender replaced?

Tags: rendering

Hello and thanks in advance for any assistance anyone might be able to provide, and for your time and effort in any case.

Earlier I was in the process of creating a sequence of renders to combine into an animation, and I realized that, though I am sure I did in fact save each one, there were some missing. I was in the process of rendering a frame at the time, so I allowed it to finish and saved it as (Project name)?, given that I didn't want to risk mislabeling as belonging in a certain position in the sequence. Blender apparently responded to this by renaming the file (Project name)a which was the name of the first render in my sequence, and given that the sequence is one in which the mesh is deformed more and more over the course of the sequence and I cannot just undo all the way back to the original undeformed mesh, I need some way to either retrieve that original state of the mesh, or at least my original render.

Comment: It looks like you saved new render atop of the old render with the same name and probably with [*Overwrite* option](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/output/output.html#output-panel) enabled. If this is the case then I think there's no way to recover the file of the rewritten image in sequence.